# O que significa h1 no html?

Tags: html

Boa noite, comecei a estudar html e estou indo na prática pela primeira vez, e gostaria de saber o que significa o `<h1>` no meu código. Uso o replit e peguei um código que vinha assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>???</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Ai gostaria de saber o que significa esse `<h1>`.

Comment: Recomendamos que se tiver dúvidas, sobre tags que ainda não conhece, leia a documentação da MDN e nessa página https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element busque pela tag que deseja entender melhor.

Answer (score -3):

Olá, boa tarde! A TAG "h1" é usada para títulos. Há 6 TAGs desse tipo: "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5" e "h6". No caso o "h1" seria o titulo maior.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Boa noite Guinomio!
Começando, o `<h1>` é uma TAG do HTML, nele você pode utilizar para ser como título.
No inicio de aprendizado da linguagem, utilize ele como título e logo quando você aprender mais a fundo sobre o html, vai conhecer o CSS onde poderá personalizar o seu site do jeito que quiser.
Bons estudos!

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).